# How to work with SpeechAPI5.* in Windows 10 with Delphi XE2 or higher?

Tags: delphi, windows-10, text-to-speech, sapi, microsoft-speech-api

I have example for **SpeechAPI 5.4** in Delphi XE2. Here's part of it:

```
try
  SpVoice:= TSpVoice.Create(nil);
  SOTokens := SpVoice1.GetVoices('', '');
  for i := 0 to SOTokens.Count - 1 do begin
    SOToken := SOTokens.Item(I);
    SOToken._AddRef;
    s:=SOToken.GetDescription(0); // raise exception
    Log(IntToStr(i)+': '+s);
  end;
except
  on E : Exception do begin
    Log(E.ClassName+' error raised, with message : '+E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

This code works correct on all Windows from XP till 8.1. Unfortunately, Windows 10 raise exception. In **log file** I can read:

```
0: Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)
EOleException error raised, with message : OLE error 8004503A
```

Standard Windows Text-to-speech tool shows me 2 **available voices**:

```
Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)
Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)
```

It's important create `TSpVoice` dynamically.

How can I work with all voices without exceptions?

Comment: I have worked with SAPI in Windows 7. Haven't worked with it in Windows 10 tho. `0x8004503a` means `SPERR_NOT_FOUND`: `The requested data item (data key, value, etc.) was not found.` Can you try this: http://nextup.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6641 - Does this work on Windows 10?

Comment: what updates did you install to Delphi ? can you work this with Update pack 3 ? That is not the same but in Delphi XE2 Update 4 they broken some COM parts and made MS Office interaction broken until a patch is applied. Maybe (just maybe) that could affect you too. https://github.com/the-Arioch/XE2fixes

Comment: Updated, line where ``SOToken.GetDescription(0)`` called

Comment: @Arioch'The I use ``Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2 with Update 4 Hotfix 1 x32`` compiler. Unfortunately I can't use Update 3 because we have big developer group and it's not to easy to change compilers for all. Tanks for link, I'll try to use it.

Comment: what interface is `SOToken` ? Does it have something like `.Count` or `.Length` or `.IsEmpty` ? What if there really is not a single element within some containers, not even the zeroth one ? Can you put a guard before `GetDescription` - something like `if SOToken is not empty then SOToken.GetDescription(0)` ?

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes, it have. And it's not empty, not nil because I have 2 voices in system and I can get info about first of them, you can check it in log.

Comment: @0xFF Did you try the link in my comment?

Comment: @MarioWerner Still no. Unfortunately I have no direct access now at those PC, so I can try it today's evening or tomorrow

Comment: @0xFF `And it's not empty, not nil because I have 2 voices in system ` - that proves nothing. System can give you one SOToken with two voices inside, or 10 SOToken's of which 8 would be empty and two would contain one voice each. At least that is so until proven otherwise. So I reinstate my suggestion to check each and every obtained SOToken how many items it has inside. You should realise - all your assumptions like `And it's not empty, nor nil` are already failed. If your assumptions were true - you would not have exceptions. You do have exceptions. That means your assumptions are not valid.

Comment: `SOToken._AddRef;` - why do you do it? Where do you call `SOToken._Release;` in the loop ?

Comment: @Arioch'The It's only part of code. I call ``SOToken._Release;`` when I stop to use voice components.

Comment: Delphi automatically calls both AddRef and Release. When you manually call that it is a code smell, it usually means that either the code or Delphi was broken and that error could not be fixed so the ugly hack-around with explicit AddRef calls was introduced. That is why i asked.

Comment: When calling explicitly for example you have to ensure the variable never changes its value nor goes out of lifetime scope between calls to AddRef and Release. That is not only tedious but error-prone as well....

Comment: @Arioch'The I tried without ``SOToken._Release;`` and I had the same result.

Comment: By removing Release you introduce memory leak and what not. In good code there would be neither explicit AddRef nor explicit Release. There should be an exotic and compelling reason to ever call them manually. Normally Delphi calls them automagically and you do not touch those methods ever.

Comment: @Arioch'The Thank you for advice, I'll remove both of them.

Comment: Do a simple test - in the end of the loop add SOToken := nil;, then put a breakpoint there. When it would stop here go View, Debug Windows, CPU View - if the type of SOToken is declared correctly you would see Delphi compiler inserted the call to Release itself. You would also easily spot difference between compiled interface types of variable and interpreted Variant/OLEVariant types, the latter would call a complex intermediate RTL procedure before at last calling Release

Comment: In your quoted code it would be a good idea to nil the SOToken variable right after the loop, so it would let the object go as soon as you exited the loop and no more need it. I once was personally hit by the code that did not cleared interface variable inside a long function. The function later tried to modify the resource being modified by the object held by that interface variable until the end of the function (and the local variable lifetime). With some versions of interface providing libraries it worked, but with others function was corrupting data due to race conditions.

Comment: @Arioch'The Now I use SpVoice only in one method so it's a local variable. But thank you for advice. Unfortunately my customer has some problems with his laptop and I can't test proposed variants yet. Can you give me some instruction how to use your bugfix for XE2?

Comment: @0xff I do not quite remember, just look into it - either both units have two public functions to patch RTL / undo patching, or they do it automatically from initialization/finalization as soon as you use those units somewhere

Comment: @0xff just be warned. In my case it also was a single function, it just was long enough to do more than trivial things and make conflict with forgotten variable's object...   praemonitus praemunitus

Comment: a bit of nit-picking - there is no such thing as x32, there is x86 and x64 :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The I looked at ``SOToken``, it's an interface ``ISpeechObjectToken``:
http://www.daisy.org/projects/pipeline/doc/api/transformers/se_tpb_speechgen2/external/win/sapi5/ISpeechObjectToken.html
So, it has no any ``count`` and ``size`` methods. It's only one Token per one voice. Unfortunately I didn't find documentation for it at MSDN, only this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722610(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What is Delphi declaration of SpObjectToken interface? In the example the GetDescription method takes no parameters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722596.aspx - in MS Office VBA vs Delphi that usually means there is `LCID` requested locale param implicit in VBA and explicit in compiled languages. And there was a bug in Excel that cells (iRange type) only executed some method in one specific locale.... And i do not think 0 is correct value, maybe SYSTEM_LOCALE or DEFAULT_LOCALE to be tried... Find and read Delphi declaration of that datatype!

Comment: Your Java page also claims there goes locale id - so read MSDN about Windows locales and about how to construct valid LCID

Comment: Your MSDN link claims locale should be optional though.... But something obviously is going differently than estimated and planned.... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722602.aspx or maybe there indeed is registry corruption. Win10 installer sucks...

Comment: @MarioWerner Unfortunately your proposition didn't help. I think I should try new compiler, maybe it's really Delphi bug for new Windows versions.

Comment: @Arioch'The The ``0`` is default value, so it's correct code.

Comment: You can not try xe2u3 but u can try post-xe2? Like i said, all the assumptions failed, if there is an exception. Personally i see no documentation on MSDN about how the call would react to unexpected LCID. So i suggest you to try two defaults above and an American English locale too. There ma be all kinds of problems, in Delphi, Windows, voice module, Windows installation instance, whatever....

Comment: @Arioch'The it's only part of truth, but I think it's dirty solution try to guess locale for each voice. I'll try XE2u3, but if XE6 or higher solve my problem I'll have more benefits from XE6. On the other hand I'll have some problems with migration to higher version of compiler. think I can get a conclusion only after testing both of the variants.

Comment: You might also make a DLL in xe6, FPC or even C++ to query the list of voices, and call that DLL from your main app. Or you can try to utilize Windows Scripting Host and query voices via VBScript or JScript

Comment: @Arioch'The I've got results of small test app from test computer. Unfortunately not XE2u3 nor Delphi 10 Seattle didn't fix this error. I had the same error message: ``EOleException error raised, with message : OLE error 8004503A``

Comment: I say it again - from my experience with Excel COM - try the three LCIDs I mentioned above.  BTW, today Windows 10 foregone massive platform update